# How can I combine the scores of a multilabel classifier?

Tags: python, keras, statistics, multilabel-classification, multiclass-classification

I have a keras neural network with 8 outputs and it is a multilabel problem, which means that an observation can be classified into more than one target class.

Let's suppose I have the following vector of 8 probabilities (events A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H) calculated by the model to a given observation:

**[0.31, 0.45, 0.89, 0.02, 0.43, 0.21, 0.96, 0.32]**

So, we can interpret that:

**P(A) = 0.31, P(B) = 0.45 and so on...**

But what if I want the probability of an observation belong to classes A or B, for example (**P(A or B) = ?**). Or the probability **P(A and B) = ?**

I imagine there are some things to take in consideration, like:

1. Are the events independent?
2. How can I check the intersection of the events?

I would appreciate references of how can I approach this problem.

Comment: you'll probably be better off asking on https://stats.stackexchange.com/ or reddit. I think that you'll need the probability values to be calibrated for such reasoning to make sense.

Comment: thanks @YuriFeldman, i will try to ask there.

Comment: Good question, agreed it's suitable for stats.se. That said, you can work from basic definitions to get the results you need. The calculations needed depend on what's assumed by the classification model. If the outputs are normalized so they sum to 1, that's assuming the classes are mutually exclusive, therefore P(A and B) = 0, P(A or B) = P(A) + P(B). If each output can be 0 to 1 and the sum is not normalized, that's assuming the classes are not exclusive, and there is a more complex relation. Good luck and have fun.